# PyCharm doesn't recognise imported module from sibling to project root folder

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
python_projects
|
|- common_tools
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- some_functions.py
|
|- some_project
   |- main.py
```

I currently import `some_functions.py` into `main.py` as follows, similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/17177597):

```
import sys
import os

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(CURRENT_DIR))
from common_tools import some_functions
```

This seems to work correctly and Python raises no errors when calling `some_functions.a_function()`. However, Pycharm doesn't seem to recognise the references to `common_tools` or `some_functions`, and thus doesn't automatically suggest `a_function()` when I type `some_functions`.

I have seen answers which handle including modules within `some_project`, but I plan to use `common_tools` for several other projects (which would be located as siblings to `some_project`) and would prefer to keep the folder structure in such a way that I can set up each individual project to access `common_tools` without having to have a separate copy of the module within each project folder.

I have tried adding various folders to `Content Root` and/or marking them as `Sources...`, but I haven't found a combination that seems to work yet. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Add `python_project` as Content Root and `common_tools` as Sources.

Comment: you may have to add to `sys.path` parent folder `os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "..")` if you want `from common_tools import some_functions` or `os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "..", "common_tools")` if you want `import some_functions`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.